# Prevent Jupyter Lab from producing empty checkpoint files when running .ipynb files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-lab

I use Visual Studio Code for running .ipynb files. Upon opening a .ipynb file, Jupyter Lab (which I am guessing is the culprit here, and not Visual Studio Code) produces empty checkpoint files on the format `<file_name>-3e052707-91a6-4ce0-a6d1-07aee1a5ff1f.ipynb`. This clogs the directory and is generally annoying. Does anyone know how to disable this "feature"?

Comment: I think you are confusing JupyterLab with notebook implementation available in VScode. Those are completely separate applications (despite some marketing from MS making it easy to confuse the two). [JupyterLab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab) does not create files with checkpoints like that (to my knowledge).

Comment: Got you. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Nope, I'm just commenting to suggest removing an incorrect tag; sorry I can't help with VSCode, but let me know if you have questions about JupyterLab.